# React keep to single setState call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

Supposed that in a function, i always need to set `someState`, and only need to set `someOtherState` if `condition` is true.

Is it preferable to do it like this:

```
this.setState({ someState });

if (condition) {
  this.setState({ someOtherState });
}
```

Or this?

```
if (condition) {
  this.setState({ someState, someOtherState });
} else {
  this.setState({ someState });
}
```

I know React is optimized such that calling `setState` in quick succession will usually not result in a re-render. But is that behavior guaranteed or should the code make such assumption?

eg. supposed it works by re-rendering on a fixed time interval, if the first `setState` get called right before that interval block ends, then the second `setState` will result in a re-render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use ternary operator? If condition is true, set it to new state. Otherwise, use the old one.

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  someState,
  someOtherState: condition ? newSomeOtherState : prevState.someOtherState
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

React batches setState calls, so doing sequential update calls should only trigger one call to render.

You can assume that it will be batched provided you are within React managed event functions (React event system). For example, if it's an AJAX call, or some other delayed function like a promise or setTimeout, they will not be batched.

**EDIT**
[This post](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/) has a pretty good summary of the order of events in most situations. You will find the state section about halfway down, but I'll try to summarise here:

Order goes :

1. Updating State
2. ShouldComponentUpdate
3. ComponentWillUpdate
4. Render
5. ...

If you're calling multiple functions within one of these, React is smart enough to wait until they're complete before running the batched updates.

See the React docs here for details on setState:

(Link limit: facebook.github.io)/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

and also a discussion on batching here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/G6pljvpTGX0

Comment: Will it definitely be batched even if the `setState` is called in different functions? i.e. event loop only get flushed when main loop finished execution aka is idling?

Comment: It depends on your code and where it's running. It's mostly determined by the order react functions run in. But speaking generally, different functions will still batch if they're within the lifecycle before the render, if that makes sense.

Comment: "within the lifecycle before the render"
how is that lifecycle determined?